# How to figure out port information in mininet

Tags: openflow, mininet

I use python to create a custom mininet topology. To know the topology in detail is not important for the question.

I use ryu as controller. Especially I use the app "ofctl_rest.py". This controller does not install rules in the switch on its own. You have to issue rest - commands to establish rules. In every rest request (rule) you have to specify an outgoing port. To specify this port I need information about the topology of the network.

I need to know which link is connected to a port. I need to know which interface the port runs on. Also helpful would be to know the foreign interface, foreign switch/host, and foraign port of the actual port. How can I retrieve this information???

Please help me. I am really frustrated right now, because I do not know how to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the mininet CLI you can use the `net` command to find out about the topology. The `nodes`  command will show you a list of nodes.
You can also use the `dump` command to display the interface details.

For information on the 'hosts', such as they are, you can run normal linux commands on each host, e.g.

```
mn> h1 ifconfig
```

will run `ifconfig` on host `h1`, showing you some of the network configuration for that host.

Given that you seem to be running mininet from a custom script, you could start the CLI at the end of your script (if that's possible) e.g.

```
net = Mininet(your_topo)
net.start()
CLI(net)
net.stop()
```

Otherwise, you can use the mininet python APIs to find much of the information.

- the `dump*` functions in [mininet.util](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/mininet/util.py) will print out lots of information.
- `topo.links()` will give you a list of the links in the topology.
- `topo.linkinfo()` might give you some extra info.

For flow information you can either run [`ovs-dpctl`](http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-dpctl.8.html), [ovs-ofctl](http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.html) etc. outside of mininet (in a normal shell), or run the equivalents without the `ovs-` prefix inside the mininet CLI.